# Search node in the parent node - xml

Tags: c#, xml, io

I want to search a specific node within the parent node,

I tried to do it this way:

```
public string GetNodeValue(XmlNode myNode, string nodeName, string parentName)
{
  return myNode.SelectSingleNode("//"+parentName).SelectSingleNode("//"+nodeName).InnerText;
}

private void SetXmlFile(string path)
    {
       XmlDocument _doc = new XmlDocument();
        _doc.Load(path);

        foreach (XmlNode node in _doc.SelectNodes("//MyNodeName"))
        {
           GetNodeValue(node,"NodeChildeName1","NodeParentName2");
        }

    }
```

My xml looks like this:

```
<SomeNode Name="x">
    <a>a1</a>
    <a>a2</a>
    <a>a3</a>
</SomeNode >
<MyNodeName Name="a1">
    <NodeParentName1>
        <NodeChildeName1>0</NodeChildeName1>
        <NodeChildeName2>40</NodeChildeName1>       
    </NodeParentName1>
    <NodeParentName2>
        <NodeChildeName1>1000</NodeChildeName1>
        <NodeChildeName2>70</NodeChildeName1>       
    </NodeParentName2>
</MyNodeName >
```

I do not get the correct value, it seems that he takes the first node that has the name, and not the first node of the parent node. (I get 0 and not 1000)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The // in GetNodeValue is causing your xpath query to start from the root directory.  Remove the // from your GetNodeValue method.

```
public string GetNodeValue(XmlNode myNode, string nodeName, string parentName)
{
    return myNode.SelectSingleNode(parentName).SelectSingleNode(nodeName).InnerText;
}
```

You could also just query the doucment like such:

```
_doc.SelectSingleNode("//MyNodeName/NodeParentName2/NodeChildeName1").InnerText
```

By the way, the xml you posted is invalid.  **NodeChildeName2** has closing tags of **NodeChildeName1**